# How to broadcast referral to android app intallation

Tags: php, android, android-broadcast, measurement, referrals

[Not Answered, Almost Same Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571920/how-to-get-referrer-url-for-apps-downloaded-from-outside-the-market)

**To Explain My Goal:**
I have an `apk` URL that could be in a market (eg: [Google Play](https://play.google.com), [Bazaar](https://cafebazaar.ir/?l=en), etc) or could be a direct link to `apk` file.

**To Explain My Requirements**
I'll have to set referral link to broadcast it to app when installed on device.
Now we all know that `Google Play` will broadcast referral (Campaign Attribution) to app, but our native market (`Bazaar`) won't do this.

**To Explain My Problem**
Is there anyway to broadcast referral information manually by myself? if there is any way I would change all applications link to specific link that I'll generate for them to achieve referral info broadcasting.

**In Other Word**
I need to have the referrer that cause download when app installed successfully to understand that who is the real person that download and install this app from anywhere?

**More Information**
My priority is not involves with developing new application to act as a new market, but there is no limitation in technical method that you suggest. In other word I need some useful data (eg: Who Download, Who Installed from everywhere, Who Is Active, etc) about the application that I cause them to be installed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: add analytic like fabric

Comment: @Divyesh, Can I use dynamic data to broadcast to app downloaded from everywhere. I need to know if an app downloaded from specific link (each person has a different one), is it installed either and that user is active now...

Comment: dont sure about link. but you can track how many people download it and currently using it

Comment: But the most important things that I need to know is who installed the app, who makes him/her to download and install the app. Also there is not just one app, many apps that given to me

Comment: then you have to use some external service that provide referrel

Comment: by saying `service` you mean `market`? or what?

Comment: no. like mcent that track of link of app

Answer (score 1):

After searching & thinking I found an alternative way to do this in direct download.

Solution I achieved is as below:

- I have applications `apk` file on my server
- When Custom client come to download page I'll create a file contains data that make that download as a unique and known download.
- Then I'll add that file to `apk` source and rebuild & resign the package (eg: using [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/))
- Also I should wrote custom `SDK` to read the file in specific path (if exist) and send data to my server to have client info I need

In fact this scenario is in abstract mode already, so I should try to make it executable

Comment: Hello @Hossein ( https://stackoverflow.com/users/2692284/hossein-shahsahebi ) can you please share howto add a file to the apk source?

Answer (score 1):

May be, you can create different `apk` flavors(with same applicationID) for different host server/market. In different flavor you can hard code a server/market identifier variable/constant and identifier must be unique for each flavor.

So when a user opens the app , based on the identifier value you can identify the market/server URL from where app is downloaded.

Also you can try Google analytic in different `apk` flavor. For installation Tracking you can create different installation Events for different Flavor.
**I haven't tried this. Hope this help**

Comment: Thank you for your participation. your solution is correct but it couldn't fill my requirement as I have dynamic numerous flavors. Somehow There are many different customers that should have their own unique data